# Better mobile development HTML framework (JQM vs DOJO)?

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, dojo

I am developing an Android app with PhoneGap, and I am interested to know which framework the cleanest, easiest to implement and most flexible complement to PhoneGap?

I did some research and it appears that most popular ones are DOJO and JQuery Mobile. Advantages and disadvantages of both? Which one is more HTML5ish and which one is easier to use?

I am doing rapid application development, so learning curve and development time is a major factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- JM is updated much more regularly compared to DOJO
- Many more people use jQuery than DOJO, making it much easier to research solutions that you may need
- JM also has much more documentation than DOJO, although it has recently improved. If you take a look at JM documentation, you will see just how much they give to you.
- jQuery library is slightly smaller than DOJO
- JM has a very simple UI
- Very easy get going and use JM
- JM targets a variety of devices
- DOJO is geared more towards MVC

I have not used DOJO so I am not able to give you much pertaining to it, other than aspects of research that I have done in the past when trying to decide on a framework. Never the less I have/am using JM (with phonegap) and feel that it is quite simple to implement and will only continue to become better in the future.